# Different activities or same activity but different layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an app where basically i have X different activities but everyone has a layout equals to the rest. To let you understand better let me do an example:
Suppose i have a game where you have to guess 10 words each level, and I have 5 levels, basically I have in every view 10 question. 
So is better to have 5 different activities or only one activity and 5 layouts, one for every level ?
Looking around on the web i did not find a good answer, someone told that Android is based on activity, so 10 different ones is the way to go, but was only a guessing, nothing technical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make 10 Activities. Don't make 5 layouts. All questions look the same except for the text, right? Don't Repeat Yourself.

Simplify your life reuse the same Activity and Layout for every single question.
When you start the activity, you can pass in data using the [.putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) methods. Use that to pass in the things that change, like the question text, the correct answer, and the current level.

Comment: thanks alot, and in case one level has more elements than another, can I modify the layout without losing efficiency ?

Comment: Sure, using something like a LinearLayout you can add several views in a for loop. A more advanced (and eventually better) method would be to learn about and use a ListView and an Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I would do 1 layout and then program the levels onto it.

Doing a brick breaker game, or tetris, or puzzle game wouldnt want you to have a million diff activity options, but more like 1 layout and 1 activity will populate accordingly.

Usually you can do something like
[home] -> {play, options, exit}

[play] -> {new game, level select}

[options] -> ....derp...

[exit] -> ....derp...

[newgame] --> start activityA where level = 1

[level select] -> click a link which will start activityA with a level = selected.

1 activity which will spawn your information safe and nicely... far far better imo.

Comment: Thanks, so in your opinion i can use one activity for all levels and one layout for each one ? In this way i can create all the levels then with setContentView() i can choose the right one, am i right ?